# XAML Listbox binding List form another .cs

Tags: wpf, xaml

a Student need a little help:

I got a List in my main Window and want to bind it to a Listbox in my UserControl.

My Mainwindow Code for the List:

```
    public  List<T> test_list;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        test_list= new List<T>(); //creating the list
        test_list_fill(); // filling the list with some stuff
    }
```

In the UserControl .cs it is not possible to use `Listbox1.ItemsSource = test_list;` due to the fact that test_list is unkown, which is nothing special. 
My question is there antoher way to get the test_list filled in the Listbox1 ?

I tryed some XAML stuff, but i won't get it to work.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source=test_list}" 
         Margin="17,130,17,118" >
```

This at least displays "test_list" in the Listbox, but thats not the content of my list. I know that i later need stuff like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"` to display the content, but i wont even get the binding. Is there any solution without having `Listbox1.ItemsSource = test_list;` in the UserControl.cs ?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day typing some code !

Answer (score 0):

Make it a property. Binding won't work with fields.

```
public List<T> test_list {get;set;}
```

and, also, you should provide type of what you want to be instead of `T` in `List<T>` like `List<string>`, `List<int>`, `List<Customer>` etc.

Update: Here are some other details:
-You put this list in code behind file. Binding is done with the object that is in `DataContext` property of the control and this is usually another class (this is called ViewModel) and not the same class as `Window`.
-If you created list **after** `InitializeComponent()` is called, then it will not be loaded because Bindings are already done and there were no list (yet). To detect change in property, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (there is a lot of examples online).
-If you will later change items in list and want to reflect that in UI, use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` and it will notify when some element is added or removed.

So, complete solution would be to:
-Create separate class that will have property `test_list`
-Make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise event from it in setter of the property
-If you will add/remove elements, use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.
-Set instance of this class to `DataContext` property of the `Window`.

Comment: Done. Got a scrollbar on the Listbox now, but still no value. Do i need to change something with `ItemsSource="{Binding Source=test_list}"` ? This way there is a large white beam i can cklick on, with `ItemsSource="{Binding test_list}"` there is nothing.

Comment: I updated answer with some additional details. It is more completed and details solution. If you get stuck, let me know :) Also, check online MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your `UserControl.cs` which will be the `ItemSource` for your `ListBox` in the user control. 
In `UserControl.cs`:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _firstNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> FirstNames { get { return _firstNames; } } 

    public void PopulateNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
             _firstNames.Add(name); 
        }
    }
```

In your Usercontrol.xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstNames}"/>
```

Now, from the parent's constructor:

```
var names = new List<string>() {"James", "bond"};
myusercontrol.PopulateNames(names);
```

Instead of a `List`, you would want to use `ObservableCollection` because it has a change notification mechanism built in. Therefore, once you set the `Binding` in `xaml` to the `ObservableCollection`, it will be reflected in UI without you having to execute additional code. Also remember that when using `ObservableCollection`, for changes to reflect in `UI` you shouldn't `new` up a different one, instead you should modify the one you initially created.

This is not the ideal way however, you should look into `MVVM` pattern as you progress further. This should solve what you asked for though.